# iOS 17 Simulator and SDKs getting uninstalled intermittently

Tags: xcode, simulator, ios17

we are using Xcode 15 (and have used almost all beta releases for this test) with iOS 17 simulator and related SDK.

However, we notice that all of a sudden the iOS 17 simulator becomes incompatible and SDKs are getting removed. We are using a hot desking on a mac which also removes the user Library on every logout, not sure that could be related. Nothing great in the logs. Any idea why this could be happening? Happy to explain in details if needed.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

We have tried reinstalling the app and also nothing is helpful in the logs

Answer (score 1):

Although my response is delayed, I'll share the solution I found. I also experienced the deactivation of iOS 17.0.0, and the simulator was downloading via the Run button but unable to build.

1. Check for Xcode updates in the App Store (updated).
2. Press cmd + shift + 2 or go to [ Window ] -> [ Devices and Simulators ].
3. Access 'Simulators' in the top left corner.
   [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB8lS.png)
4. Click the + button at the bottom left to create a new simulator.
   [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RIam.png)
5. Verify the newly created devices.
   [third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTQSI.png)